# How to change the IO policy to noop on centos 8 for all kernel?

Tags: linux, centos, io

I want to change the IO policy to noop for all the VMs of all kernel version. (Even if there is a future updated version also)

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
Output as follow
[mq-deadline] kyber bfq none

grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="elevator=noop"
reboot

Even after applying the following command also, policy was not updated. 

"[mq-deadline] kyber bfq none"
```

Additionally tried the following command also

```
Modified the /etc/default/grub with elevator=noop
and ran the command  grub2-mkconfig
```

still the the IO policy is not updated on Centos 8

In centos 8, how to update the IO policy to noop?

Answer (score 1):

From [kernel 5.4](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/85c0a037dc7a1a34d6add49d6eaa2deddbf43d7b) `elevator=` argument has been removed.

> Since the inclusion of blk-mq, elevator argument was not being
> considered anymore, and it's utility died long with the legacy IO path,
> now removed too.

You can use `udev` rules or `tuned` profiles

**udev**

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/60-ioschedulers.rules

# set noop scheduler for non-rotating disks
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="0", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="noop"

# set noop scheduler for rotating disks
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="1", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="noop"
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution which worked is

> It's no longer present in newer kernels. Use "none" instead.

For more details: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=75002